# Translate, rotate and tilt using OpenGL shaders

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader

I'm a OpenGL noob, but I nevertheless need to solve the following problem using OpenGL Es 2.0 shaders:

Given a geometry in 2D space:

- translate the geometry's x and y
- rotate the geometry around the origin point (bottom left in screen space)
- Apply perspective correction to the geometry using the current camera in 3D (lookat, up,..)

The result will be a 2D -> 3D transformed geometry.

I guess these are basic things for someone familiar with OpenGL (ES 2). But for me, I hope to find some definitive answers for my particular usage and hopefully also some code examples. I really spend already quite some time, but beyond a basic (disfunctional) matrix transformation I did not get much far.

Ideally you could provide a code snippet and along with it an explanation for any of the required transformations?

To also illustrate what I'm trying to achieve, I've photoshoped an example:

**Original geometry:**

[image]

**Translate by y + something, x + nothing:**

[image]

**Rotate geometry about bottom left origin:**

[image]

[image]

**Apply perspective correction to 2D by using current 3D camera values:**
[image]

For what it's worth, this is my current vertex shader code which currently does nothing but draw some geometry. The usage of the rotationMatrix function and the line

```
gl_Position *= rotated
```

was a lame attempt to try just any rotation about an axis, which isn't what I actually want. It was when I realized that I need your help ;)

```
        precision mediump float;
        #define LOWP lowp

        attribute vec2 a_position;
        attribute vec2 a_screenPosition;
        attribute vec2 a_uvs;
        attribute float a_alpha;
        attribute float a_rotation;

        uniform mat4 u_proj;

        varying vec2 v_uv;
        varying float v_alpha;

        mat4 rotationMatrix(vec3 axis, float angle)
        {
            axis = normalize(axis);
            float s = sin(angle);
            float c = cos(angle);
            float oc = 1.0 - c;

            return mat4(oc * axis.x * axis.x + c,           oc * axis.x * axis.y - axis.z * s,  oc * axis.z * axis.x + axis.y * s,  0.0,
                        oc * axis.x * axis.y + axis.z * s,  oc * axis.y * axis.y + c,           oc * axis.y * axis.z - axis.x * s,  0.0,
                        oc * axis.z * axis.x - axis.y * s,  oc * axis.y * axis.z + axis.x * s,  oc * axis.z * axis.z + c,           0.0,
                        0.0,                                0.0,                                0.0,                                1.0);
        }

        void main() {
            if (a_alpha != 0.0) {
                float st = sin(a_rotation);
                float ct = cos(a_rotation);

                // rotates first around +z-axis (0,0,1) and then translates by (tx,ty,0)
                vec4 p = vec4(
                    a_position.x * ct - a_position.y * st + a_screenPosition.x,
                    a_position.x * st + a_position.y * ct + a_screenPosition.y,
                    0.0, 1.0
                );

                mat4 rotated = rotationMatrix(vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), 45.0);
                gl_Position = u_proj * p;
                gl_Position *= rotated;
        //        gl_Position = u_proj * p;
            } else {
                gl_Position = vec4(0.0);
            }

            v_uv = a_uvs;
            v_alpha = a_alpha;
        }
```

Comment: I don't think it is your problem, but you *really* want to use highp, not mediump, for anything involving position (mediump is fine for computing color values when you are output 8-bt per channel, but not so good for 3D position or 2D texture coordinate computation).

Comment: If you are not sure how it works, I'd also recommend prototyping this in C on a CPU - it's a whole load easier to debug, and easy to port once you have it working ...

Answer (score -1):

The better solution it's matrix transformation. Working in vertex shader means that you build matrix transformation for each vertex!

Rethink your code, if you had trouble with matrix transformation. I work on Android, but concepts are the same.

http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/

Last but not least, try to use https://github.com/libgdx/ to begin study 3D graphics. It's a library multiplatform and Opengl based. Moreover, it's open source.